# Python counter unexpected result for most_common(). Is it a bug in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across unexpected result. And I do not understand why this happens when I use collections.Counter

I use python 3.8

```py
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
counter["تمباکو"] = +1
print(counter.most_common())
```

Output:

```py
    [('تمباکو', 1)]
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) it should returns (keywords, count) pair

When I try to write to csv the output of counter.most_common() it also changes the order of the data:

```py
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(counter.most_common())
```

it outputs in rows pairs (count, keyword)

but when you run:

```py
counter.most_common()[0][0]
```

it will output:

```py
'تمباکو'
```

and it looks like everything is fine, because keywords is first.

Something is wrong and I do not understand it.

Comment: Your input string has an RTL override character, since it's in Arabic script (that's read from right to left). That's what's screwing up your output there, making it look like it's on the right.

Comment: "According to the documentation it should returns (keywords, count) pair" And it does. The problem is that `print`, on your system, is not equipped to handle that particular Arabic string. If you look closely, you'll notice that the quote marks in your reported input are in strange places, too. There are other ways to fail. My terminal, for example, does not support those characters at all; so when I copy and paste your code, I just see boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

It's not Python, it's your input.

Here's a synthetic example that has a string including [U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE](https://unicode-table.com/en/202E/) (which, humorously, affects the rendering on that linked page too).

```
from collections import Counter

s = "\u202Ehello"
c = Counter()
c[s] += 1

for word, count in c.most_common():
    print(word, count)
```

When I run this, my terminal shows

```
‮hello 1
```

since the 202E character overrides rendering order.

If I remove the 202E character, I get

```
hello 1
```

as expected.

A way to print strings that have such override characters in a "de-fanged" way is to use `repr()` (with its own caveats, of course):

```
for word, count in c.most_common():
    print(repr(word), count)
```

prints out

```
'\u202ehello' 1
```

since the offending control character is escaped.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of that 202E character